# Eisenstein series for hexagonal lattice

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, integer-lattices

How I don't know how to prove that given the lattice $\Lambda=\lbrace m\rho+n \: : \: m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\rbrace$ with $\rho\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\lbrace 1\rbrace$ such that $\rho^3=1$, the Eisenstein series $$G_4(\Lambda):=\sum_{\omega\in \Lambda\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace}\dfrac{1}{\omega^4}=0.$$
Any help?

Comment: The lattice is invariant under $\omega \mapsto \rho\omega$ but under such a transform, the summand picks up a $\rho^{-4} \ne 1$ factor. If the series converges, then the sum has to be $0$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more your answer?

Comment: Achille's comment is a mix between all our answers.

Comment: Yup, it is a mix among all answers. It comes down to if a number $x$ satisfies $\rho^{-4} x = x$ but $\rho^{-4} \ne 1$, then $x = 0$.

Comment: When you say invariant under $\rho\mapsto\rho\omega$, do you mean $\rho\Lambda=\Lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise, you can use the properties of the modular group and modular forms.

Note that $\scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\displaystyle e^{2i \pi / 3}=\frac{-1}{e^{2i \pi / 3}} = e^{2i \pi / 3}+1$

Since [$G_4$ is a modular form of weight $4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) :  $$G_4(\scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\displaystyle \tau) = \tau^4 G_4(\tau), \qquad G_4(\tau) = G_4(\tau+1)$$ and
$$G_4(e^{2i \pi / 3}) = G_4(e^{2i \pi / 3}+1) = G_4(\scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\displaystyle e^{2i \pi / 3}) = e^{8 i \pi / 3}G_4(e^{2i \pi / 3})$$
i.e. $G_4(e^{2i \pi / 3}) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Since the sum converges absolutely, you can regroup the terms in group of threes $\{\omega ; \rho \omega ; \rho^2 \omega\}$. The sum on each group is $0$, and they partition the index set, so the whole sum is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$G_k$ is homogeneous of degree $k$, i.e., $$G_k(a\Lambda)=\frac{G_k(\Lambda)}{a^k}$$
for all nonzero $a\in \mathbb{C}$. 
If $a\Lambda=\Lambda$ then the homogeneity implies that $G_k(\Lambda)$ can only be nonzero if $a^k = 1$. Therefore $G_k(\Lambda)=0$ for the equilateral triangular lattice $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\rho$, unless $6\mid k$. In particular, $G_4(\Lambda)=0$.

Comment: You need to use the modularity for showing $G_4(e^{2i \pi / 3}) = 0$ from its transformation law